# Double gets rounded automatically?

Tags: java, integer, double

I might have been staring at my screen too much because of programming, but I really don't understand what is happening here.

I'm trying to make a game and calculate the percentage progress it takes to level up. Here are my methods:

```
public static int currentLevelInt(Integer XP){
    return (int)(1 + sqrt(1+8*XP/50))/2;
}

public static double currentLevelDouble(Integer XP){
    return (1 + sqrt(1+8*XP/50))/2;
}

public static int getPercentage(Integer XP){
    double currentLevel = currentLevelDouble(XP);
    int nextLevel = currentLevelInt(XP)+1;
    return (int)(100-((nextLevel-currentLevel)*100));
}
```

Let's say I have 54 XP. Then these are the expected values:

```
currentLevelInt(54) = 2
currentLevelDouble(54) = 2.05241747
(int)(100-(((currentLevelInt(54)+1)-currentLevelDouble(54))*100)) = 5%
//+1 because I need the next Level
```

But these are the values I get returned:

```
currentLevelInt(54) = 2
currentLevelDouble(54) = 2.0
(int)(100-(((currentLevelInt(54)+1)-currentLevelDouble(54))*100)) = 0%
//+1 because I need the next Level
```

I don't understand what is going on? I'm passing the double as double, why would it be rounded off to 2.0?

Comment: this `1+8*XP/50` is all `int` so the result will automaticly be an `int` (the biggest from the expression). Then, you have `1 + sqrt(1+8*54/50))/2` -> `1 + sqrt(9))/2`

Comment: @AxelH Wow, I have never encountered this problem or noticed it before in all my programming time. How do I get around this, do I use the Math library?

Comment: Just turn any of the operands of your division to a `double` - e.g. by using `/50.0`. Alternatively, you can also use a cast which might make the intention more explicit.

Comment: @Hulk Oh I see, so if I turn everything into doubles it should work, like so: `(1.0 + sqrt(1.0+8.0*XP/50.0))/2.0` and the XP into a double too?

Comment: Yes, but one would be enough - either `8.0` or `((double)XP)` or `50.0` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Hulk, not any ! it need to be the divider because the type will define during the evaluation so `8.0 + 52/50` will gave `8.0 + 1` since the division will be done first ( int / int -> int). Set this using the priority of operator -> `8+52/50.0`

Comment: @AxelH but the expression mentioned by the OP is `8.0 * XP / 52`, not `8.0 + 52/50` (and I explicitly said "any of the operands *of your division*").  `8.0 * 50 / 52` yields 7.6923076923076925, just like `8*50.0/52` or `8*50/52.0`.

Comment: @Hulk My bad, it was `1+8*XP` not `8+XP`. but the comment is still ok. The usage or cast in double should be done on the first operand used where a floating value might append.